# Populating a Number Field from Radio Button in Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, gravity

Could someone help me. I am using gravity forms and have a set up a number of radio buttons with associated prices to donate i.e. $5.00, $10.00, $25.00 etc so that people can select a pre-defined amount. I have a number field set to currency and want this field to be populated with the selection from the radio button, I am using this rather than the total field as I want the ability to allow a user to enter any price and overwrite the entry in this field if required.

Can you please help me as I have limited experience

Answer (score 2):

It turns out if you select "show values" you can define numeric values for the radio options. Then in the number field you can simply enable calculations and insert the radio field into the calculation. I found that answer at [this link](https://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/field-options/field-calculations/). That link is old and some of the wording has changed but it works basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

The most current version (see demo) actually has a Radio-Field-Option called "enable other choice". If you tick that specific field you can simply add a field the user may type a price in himself.

[image: Gravity Forms Radio-Buttons "Other"-Field]